# Get a date from isoyear, isoweek, and wday values

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Is there any function that provides a date from *isoyear*, *isoweek*, and *wday* values?

For example:

```
isoyear_val <- 2020
isoweek_val <- 1
wday_val <- 2

x <- magic_function(isoyear_val, isoweek_val, wday_val)
# x is "2019-12-30"
```

I know that, using Lubridate, dates can be set for functions such as `week()`:

```
x <- ymd("2012-03-26")
week(x) <- 30
# x is "2012-07-23"
```

But I have not found anything similar for ISO values.

Comment: Is `"2019-12-30"` really the correct answer for the input values of 2020, 1, and 2?

Comment: @r2evans Yes, it follows ISO 8601 conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package by @uwe called `ISOweek` you could try the following. The package has helper functions to deal with week of the year and weekday according to ISO 8601.

```
library(ISOweek)

ISOweek2date(
  sprintf(
    "%d-W%02d-%d",
    isoyear_val,
    isoweek_val,
    wday_val
  )
)
```

**Output**

```
[1] "2019-12-31"
```

Comment: That was exactly the answer I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

We may use `make_yearweek` from `tsibble`

```
library(tsibble)
as.Date(make_yearweek(year = isoyear_val, week = isoweek_val))
[1] "2019-12-30"
```

Not clear about the 'wday_val', if it meant to be the `week_start`

```
as.Date(make_yearweek(year  = isoyear_val, week = isoweek_val, 
      week_start = wday_val))
[1] "2019-12-31"
```